# Clase para sesiones seguras en Php, ¿Qué puede mejorar?

Tags: php, seguridad, sesiones

Hice esta clase para manejar sesiones seguras en Php y me gustaría saber **¿Hay algo que pueda mejorarse en el código?**

Está en Github: https://github.com/juan-carlos-correa/session-class

Igual pongo aquí el código:

```
<?php 

/**
* Clase para manejo de sesiones seguras.
*
* @version: 1.0
*
*   @author: Juan Correa.
*
*/
class Session
{

public $session_id;
private $session_token;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->initSession();   
    $this->setSessionToken();
    $this->setSessionValue('_session_token_', $this->session_token);
}

/*
* Configura caché de sesión y la inicializa
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
private function initSession()
{
    $this->setSessionCacheLimiter('private');
    $this->setSessionCacheExpire(0);
    $this->setCookieParams();

    session_start();

    $this->sessionRegenerateId();
}

/*
* Establece el limitador del caché actual
* 
* @params: String limiter: el limitador
*
* @return: void
*/
private function setSessionCacheLimiter($limiter)
{
    session_cache_limiter($limiter);
}

/*
* Establece la caducidad del caché en minutos
* 
* @params: Int minutes: duración del caché
*
* @return: void
*/
private function setSessionCacheExpire($minutes)
{
    session_cache_expire($minutes);
}

/*
* Establece los parámetros de la cookie. Su efecto dura lo mismo que el script invocador
* 
* @params: Int minutes: duración del caché
*
* @return: void
*/
private function setCookieParams()
{
    $cookie_params = session_get_cookie_params();

    session_set_cookie_params(
            $cookie_params['path'],
            $cookie_params['domain'],
            'SECURE',
            true);
}

/*
* Crea un token personalizado para mayor seguridad
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
private function setSessionToken()
{
    $this->session_token = sha1($this->session_id . 'DeveloperoShield');
}

/*
* Asigna el id de sesión al atributo session_id
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
public function setSessionId()
{
    $this->session_id = session_id();
}

/*
* Recupera el valor de session_id
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
public function getSessionId()
{
    return $this->session_id;
}

/*
* Crea un nuevo valor al array $_SESSION
* 
* @params: 
*       String name_key: nombre de la llave del array de sesión
*   String value: el valor asociado a la llave
*
* @return: void
*/
public function setSessionValue($name_key, $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$name_key] = $value;
}

/*
* Recupera un elemento del array $_SESSION
* 
* @params: String session_value: la llave del array a recuperar
*
* @return: el valor del elemento del array solicitado. Si no existe, false
*/
public function getSessionValue($session_value)
{
    if (! empty($_SESSION[$session_value]))
        return $_SESSION[$session_value];

    return false;
}

/*
* Elimina un elemento del array $_SESSION
* 
* @params: String session_value: la llave del array a eliminar
*
* @return: void
*/
public function removeSessionValue($session_value)
{
    if (! empty( $_SESSION[$session_value]))
        unset ($_SESSION[$session_value]);
}

/*
* Valida sesión iniciada usando session_token y session_id
*
*   Al autogenerarse al instanciar, siempre deben ser iguales
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: true en caso de éxito, false lo contrario
*/
public function checkSession()
{
    if ($this->session_token === $_SESSION['_session_token_'] and $this->session_id === session_id() )
        return true;

    return false;
}

/*
* Regenera el session_id cuando se deje de hacer referencia al objeto 
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->sessionRegenerateId();
}

/*
* Regenera el session_id
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
private function sessionRegenerateId()
{
    session_regenerate_id();
    $this->setSessionId();
}

/*
* Borra los datos y destruye la sesión.
* 
* @params: void
*
* @return: void
*/
public function destroy()
{
    $this->session_id = '';
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Quizás estos dos artículos te puedan ayudar en algo, Juan.
https://diego.com.es/seguridad-de-sesiones-en-php
http://php.net/manual/es/session.security.php

Comment: Gracias Hoose! de hecho algunos métodos son en base a estos artículos pues también los estuve revisando. Por eso el caché dura 0 minutos y está limitado a ser privado (evitar modificaciones con JS), también el regenerar el session_id(evitar el robo de sesión) aunque esto no garantiza la integridad :o

Comment: También estoy pensando implementar el patrón singleton a esta clase para que sea una instancia única (única sesión sin poderla clonar)